# Deleting rows on specific condition pandas (enumeration)

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have a CSV file with one column named position. Most of the rows follow the pattern that the column position always goes from 1-6 (see e.g. - row 1-12). However, for some of the rows the enumeration does not go up to 6 but already stops at 4 and a new row with position 1 starts. In this case I want to delete these rows with the position from 1-4 (see e.g. - row 13-16).

```
Example:  
index   position
row 1:  1        
row 2:  2
...
row 6:  6
row 7:  1 
...
row 12: 6  
row 13: 1
row 14: 2
row 15: 3
row 16: 4
row 17: 1
...
row 22: 6
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet for the problem. The idea is that first find the rows with position 1-4, and then create a remove list for rows. Finally drop them, and there you have it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "position": np.concatenate([
                list(range(1,7)),
                list(range(1,7)),
                list(range(1,5)),
                list(range(1,7)),
                list(range(1,5))
            ])
        })

df = df.append({'position': 1}, ignore_index=True)

df['diff_trail'] = df.position.diff()

rm_index_pos = df[df.diff_trail == -3].index - 1

# We know that 12-15 and 22-25 should be deleted

rm_index = np.ravel([list(range(i,i-4,-1)) for i in rm_index_pos])
rm_index = np.append(rm_index, df.index[-1])
print(rm_index)


df.drop(rm_index, axis=0, inplace=True) # Remove the unwanted rows.
df.drop(['diff_trail'], axis=1, inplace=True) # remove 'diff_trail' column from dataframe.

# Reset the index values.
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) 

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this pattern always persists, you can hardcode some of the solution: whenever you encounter 1 after 4, put the previous 4 indices in a list of indices you want to remove. It's not the prettiest code but it works.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'position': 
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,
    1,2,3,4,5,6,
    1,2,3,4,
    1,2,3,4,5,6]})

# every time you encounter a 1 after a 4, delete the previous four columns
index_delete = []
for index, values in enumerate(df.position.values[1:]):
    if (values == 1) and (df.position.values[1:][index - 1] == 4):
        index_delete.extend([index-3, index-2, index-1, index])

df = df.drop(index_delete)
```

Input:

```
df
    position
0          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
4          5
5          6
6          1
7          2
8          3
9          4
10         5
11         6
12         1
13         2
14         3
15         4
16         1
17         2
18         3
19         4
20         5
21         6
```

Output:

```
df
    position
0          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
4          5
5          6
6          1
7          2
8          3
9          4
10         5
11         6
16         1
17         2
18         3
19         4
20         5
21         6
```